# Why doesn't throw work in Swift?

Tags: swift

Any ideas why the following doesn't work?

```
func someFunction() throws {
    print ("this is a test")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Xcode 7?

Comment: No.  Xcode 7 is still beta.

Comment: This requires Swift 2.0 which was introduced in Xcode 7. If you're using Swift 1.2 (e.g. Xcode 6.4), then you cannot use `throws`.

Comment: Is there no error handling at all in Swift 1.2?  Looks like it.

Comment: Runtime error handling is generally handled by passing `NSError` objects, just like Obj-C. See [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html). One should not use exception handling in Obj-C code to handle runtime errors, anyway. Objc-C exceptions are solely for programming errors to be excised during development. Also, the `try`-`catch` of Swift should not be confused Obj-C exception handling: it's just a nice wrapper around the standard practice of passing around error objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that throws was introduced in swift 2.0, if you are using an earlier version then you will not be able to use it.

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=29

Comment: I'm in Xcode 6.4.  So this type of error handling isn't available in earlier versions?

Comment: I'm afraid not no. You will need to use Xcode 7 and swift 2.0 for this feature